# Angular directive calling parent controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I get my directive to call to parent's controller function? I have a directive that look like this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
some body text<br>
    <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="mainCtrl.myfunc()">Click Me from body</a>
    <photo photo-src="abc.jpg" caption="This is so Cool" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.controller('mainController', function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.myfunc = myfunc;

    function myfunc(){
        console.log("Log from myfunc");
    }
});

app.directive('photo',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<figure> <img ng-src="{{photoSrc}}" width="500px">   <figcaption>{{caption}}</figcaption>    <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="mainCtrl.myfunc()">Click Me</a></figure>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            caption: '@', 
            photoSrc: '@'
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7q9v3zz2/

When I click on `Click Me from body` link, it shows the console log message as expected. However, nothing happen when I click on `Click Me from directive`. How can I make it works?

Comment: use `&` to pass functions in to your `scope`, the same way you used `@` to pass other parameters.

Comment: Check this videotutorial about isolated scopes. It contains a practical example of what you need and it might be useful for you https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using isolated scope, so you cannot directly access parent scope as they are not inherited to the isolated scope. You could use `$parent` though (by doing `ng-click="$parent.mainCtrl.myfunc()"`). However that gets ugly and it gets tightly coupled with its parent, Instead you can use function binding (`&`).

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<figure> <img ng-src="{{photoSrc}}" width="500px">   <figcaption>{{caption}}</figcaption>    
        <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="onClick()">Click Me from directive</a></figure>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            caption: '@',
            photoSrc: '@',
            onClick: '&' //<-- Accept function binding and use it in the template
        }
    }
```

and register it at the consumer level, just so it becomes more reusable.

```
 <photo photo-src="abc.jpg" caption="This is so Cool" on-click="mainCtrl.myfunc()" />
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/513bn18b/)**

You could also use child scope creation instead of isolated scope and directly call the parent controller method.  Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fo7Louf/)